# Generating ASDoc for a Project that uses SWCs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, swc, asdoc

I'm using FlashDevelop and it's ActionScript Documentation Generator.

I have a project that uses several SWC files that are added to the `.as3proj` library. Some of the classes in my project extend classes that are in the SWC files.

Which causes errors during the ASDoc generation:

```
src\display\render\HexCell.as(18): col: 31 Error: The definition of base class CellRenderer was not found.
public class HexCell extends CellRenderer
```

`CellRenderer` is a class in `lib\UIComponents.swc` and part of the FlashIDE library:
`fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer`

How can I resolve this problem and others like it?

Comment: It looks like FlashDevelop is just using the `asdoc` command line utility to generate the documentation. I believe you just need to supply the path to the SWC files. I don't know the exact answer here for FlashDevelop, but maybe this [reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_9.html) or this [forum post](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8751) will help.

Comment: Can you compile the project into a SWF just fine? (Is the SWC detected during the compilation, that is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AsDoc** may be complicated with all its parameters, when dealing with external libraries.

A nice way I found it works is to use the **-library-path** parameter; this way the libraries will be included but they won't be documented.

For example:

```
asdoc -source-path "c:\MyProject\src" -doc-sources "c:\MyProject\src" -library-path "c:\MyProject\lib" -main-title "Pong" -output "c:\MyProject\doc"
```

Being `c:\MyProject\lib` where you store all the libraries your project needs.